# React Links in Sidebar work only on first click

Tags: reactjs, redux

Maybe I am missing something obvious here but I have a `Sidebar` component that is used on 2 pages of my app; `Blog` and `Post`. In my Sidebar component I have a dispatch to fetch some data for "pinned articles" and in my `App` I have some routes. When I click on the link in the sidebar, the link works but if I click a different link in the sidebar, nothing happens. In my redux store I have enabled logging middleware and I see the first click on the link is SUCCESS but clicking a second link in the sidebar shows nothing but CLEAR. Any suggestions?

App.jsx

```
      [... unrelated code omitted ...]
      render() {
        const { alert } = this.props;
        return (
          <div>
            {alert.message &&
              <div className={`alert ${alert.type}`}>{alert.message}</div>
            }
            <Router history={history}>
              <div>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/resource-centre" component={Blog} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/resource-centre/:id" component={Post} />
                <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
              </div>
            </Router>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Sidebar.jsx

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { articleActions } from '../../actions';
    import _ from 'lodash';

    class Sidebar extends React.Component {

      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(articleActions.fetchPinnedArticles());
      }

      render() {
        const { pinnedArticles } = this.props;

        return (
          <div>
            <h2 className="widget-title">Pinned</h2>
            <ul>
            {pinnedArticles.items && pinnedArticles.items.map(article => 
              <li className="tag-cloud-link" key={article.id}>
                <Link to={{ pathname: `/blog/${article.id}` }}>{article.title}</Link>
              </li>
            )}
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      const { pinnedArticles } = state;
      return {
        pinnedArticles
      }
    }

    const connectedSidebar = connect(mapStateToProps)(Sidebar);
    export { connectedSidebar as Sidebar };
```

articleAction.js

```
    function fetchPinnedArticles() {
      return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request());

        articleService.fetchPinnedArticles()
          .then(
            pinnedArticles => dispatch(success(pinnedArticles)),
            error => dispatch(failure(error))
          );
      };

      function request() {
        return { type: articleConstants.FETCH_PINNED_REQUEST }
      }

      function success(pinnedArticles) {
        return { type: articleConstants.FETCH_PINNED_SUCCESS, pinnedArticles }
      }

      function failure(error) {
        return { type: articleConstants.FETCH_PINNED_FAILURE, error }
      }
    }
```

articleService.js

```
    function fetchPinnedArticles() {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: authHeader()
      };
      return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/articles/pinned`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse, handleError);
    }
```

articleReducer.js

```
    export function pinnedArticles(state = {}, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case articleConstants.FETCH_PINNED_REQUEST:
          return {
            loading: true
          }
        case articleConstants.FETCH_PINNED_SUCCESS:
          return {
            items: action.pinnedArticles
          };
        case articleConstants.FETCH_PINNED_FAILURE:
          return {
            error: action.error
          };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you inspected the first link and the second link in the browser to see if they are the same? Just to eliminate that the link that React renders is the same each time.

Otherwise, you might need to also share more of your redux code, like what fetchPinnedArticles does.

Comment: Yep, different links for sure. I checked. I will update the post with the redux code

Comment: Sorry what I was asking about specifically is what the actual html looks like on the first link you click and the second link.

So what does this get rendered to:
<li className="tag-cloud-link" key={article.id}>
     <Link to={{ pathname: `/blog/${article.id}` }}>{article.title}</Link>
</li> 
in each case?

Comment: Ahhhh, nm I figured it out... state has changed I didn't watch for that in `componentDidUpdate`. I actually was doing that in the wrong component. pebkac error

Comment: ah cool, glad you got it figured out

Comment: thanks for rubber ducking @ZekeHernandez